# Centering multiple li/ul in a div

Tags: css

I have a div and inside are li and ul that I'm trying to center horizontally. I'm currently using this code:

```
 #Header #HeaderBg #HeaderIn #Wrapper #TabStrip .level1 li, ul {margin:0 !important; position: absolute !important; top: 50% !important; left: 50% !important; margin-right: -50% !important; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;}
```

However, when I use this code, it centers everything, but smushes them together instead of keeping the integrity of the list. Any ideas?

So if my div looks like this originally:
A B C D E F G
After using that code, it just looks like all those letters in the same space.

Comment: We do not know your html, but most likely that `,` in the selector is the culprit

Comment: You were right! Thank you! Can you put that in it's own thingy so I can mark that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector was a most likely misplaced `,`

```
#Header #HeaderBg #HeaderIn #Wrapper #TabStrip .level1 li, ul {}
                                                         ^
```

This means that it is two selectors one is `#Header #HeaderBg #HeaderIn #Wrapper #TabStrip .level1 li` and the other is `ul` which applies to all `ul` elements.

You most likely need to remove the `,` so you can target only the `ul` in that hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I have to wait until I can mark it as the answer, so I'll mark it when it lets me!